# Edit json response from curl response

Tags: php, json, curl

```
<?php
$json_url = "http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=xxxxx&callback=angular.callbacks._0";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$jsonString = json_encode($response, true);
$data=json_decode($jsonString);

echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The output is:

```
angular.callbacks._0({
    "disclaimer": "xx",
    "license": "xx",
    "timestamp": 1368136869,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 3.672819,
        "AFN": 53.209,
        "ALL": 107.953875,
        "AOA": 96.358934,
        "ARS": 5.214887,
         ....
        "XOF": 501.659003,
        "XPF": 91.114876,
        "ZMK": 5227.108333,
        "ZMW": 5.314783,
        "ZWL": 322.387247
    }
})
```

But i need to edit this output to this one (only with three rates (AED/AFN/AOA)). So, basically edit the json response in the section of rates. How can i do that?

```
angular.callbacks._0({
    "disclaimer": "xx",
    "license": "xx",
    "timestamp": 1368136869,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 3.672819,
        "AFN": 53.209,
        "AOA": 107.953875,
    }
})
```

Comment: Why you do `json_encode` than `json_decode`?

Comment: second parameter of `json_encode();` is a flag, not a boolean (true). Perhaps you meant to set that true in `json_decode();` and returning an assoc array.

Comment: @TamasPap The $response is a string. I need the json_encode first.

Comment: But $response is not in correct json format, if you check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$response` is not in correct `json` format:

You must remove the unnecessary parts from it:

```
$jsonString= substr($response, 21, -1);
```

You can do:

```
<?php
$json_url = "http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=5bf388eb6f7e40209b9418e6be44f04b&callback=angular.callbacks._0";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

$jsonString= substr($response, 21, -1);
$data=json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Get the list of rates
$rates = $data['rates'];

$new_rates = array();
$new_rates['AED'] = $rates['AED'];
$new_rates['AFN'] = $rates['AFN'];
$new_rates['AOA'] = $rates['AOA'];

$data['rates'] = $new_rates;

echo 'angular.callbacks._0('.json_encode($data).')';

$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: the response is a valid json format. [link](http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=5bf388eb6f7e40209b9418e6be44f04b&callback=angular.callbacks._0)

Comment: No it is not. You get a long string from `openexchangerates`, you `json_encode` it then you `json_decode` it. You actually have the same `string` in `data`. Make a `var_dump` if you don't believe me :)

Comment: The valid json is between `angular.callbacks._0(` and the `)` from the end. You have to parse this part.

Answer (score 3):

It's returning a response for jsonp.  You would need that on the client side, but not the server.  You might try:

```
http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=xxxxx
```

(i.e. omit the callback).  Otherwise take a look at their API to see if you can format the request differently to receive *pure* JSON back without the callback.

If you absolutely can't, then you can just strip off the bad parts:

```
preg_match('/{.*}/', $response, $matches);
$json = json_decode($matches[0]);
```

Once you have the valid JSON, it's a simple matter of `unset`ting:

```
unset($json->rates->XOF);
//etc.
```

You could also just write the content you need to some other object if it's easier.

You may want to take a look at the API to see if you can get only specific rates back.

Answer (score 1):

Read the JSON string into a PHP mapping array with `json_decode`, pick only the elements you need, compose a new array with them and finally reserialize it with `json_encode`.

Note: this method is more robust than a regex/string based one, as it makes sense of what it's being processed, thus allowing for mutation in the structure of the JSON, as long as the elements you need are at their places.

For selecting elements, use:

```
$keep = array("AED", "AFN", "AOA");
$data["rates"] = array_intersect_key($data["rates"], array_flip($keep));
```

Comment: "pick only the elements you need": how?